# How to get the result of the join operations?

Tags: sql, drupal, join

Whenever I tried to execute this sql query in a function module in drupal I am not able to get the results but when I try to execute this in MySQL I can view the result. My code looks like this :

```
 function _get_subject_sub_category() {

  $options = array();
  $sql = "SELECT father.Subject_Code, child.Subject_Category 
FROM {subjects} as child 
INNER JOIN {subjects} as father ON (child.Parent_Category = father.Subject_Code
AND child.Level =2 )";

  $result = db_query($sql);
  foreach ($result as $row) {


     $options[$row->father.Subject_Code] = $row->child.Subject_Category;

  }
  return $options;
  }
```

The error I encountered is in the line  $options[$row->father.Subject_Code] = $row->child.Subject_Category;`.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line:

```
$options[$row->father.Subject_Code] = $row->child.Subject_Category;
```

To this:

```
$options[$row->Subject_Code] = $row->Subject_Category;
```

The name of the table is not in the result. If you need to avoid confusion, you can use alias in your SQL query.

Comment: Yes I removed that though no error appeared but code is not able to fetch the Subject code and Subject category.

Comment: You can use print_r($row); or if you have devel module installed and enabled, you can use dsm($row, 'row'); and view your row content

Answer (score 1):

I don't know drupal and don't use php, but I would say :

remove 
`father.` in `$row->father.Subject_Code`

and

`child.` in `$row->child.Subject_Category`

as father and child are just db aliases.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, yes I removed that though no error appeared but code is not able to fetch the Subject code and Subject category unlike same code can fetch the information in MySQL I don't know what went wrong.